# How to extract the value only in a key-value pair in a list of dictionaries when a key is a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks something like (this is a very tiny subset of the actual data):

```
[{'utterance': 10,'id': 'output454', 'utterance': 'this is nice'}]
```

I want to extract every value where the key is 'utterance' so in this example, I would like the output to be (I do not want to include the key in the output itself):

```
'this is nice'
```

I have tried doing a few things, none of which worked (none of the below worked):

```
[key for key, val in data.items() if key== "'utterance'"]

for k, v in data.iteritems():
    if k == '"utterance":':
        print(data[k])
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: I believe that when you assign a key multiple times, the last value gets precedence. So when you `print({'utterance': 10,'id': 'output454', 'utterance': 'this is nice'})` you get `{'utterance': 'this is nice', 'id': 'output454'}`. Therefore, you cannot get all assigned values. Also, your question in general is confusing. If you just want to get `'this is nice'`, why not just do `print(data['utterance'])`?

Comment: You have 2 keys `'utterance'`

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: but the dictionary here does have many keys that are 'utterance', this is a dictionary that already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension here becomes easier if you first loop over the outer list:

```
>>> mylist = [{'utterance': 10,'id': 'output454', 'utterance': 'this is nice'}]
>>> values = []
>>> for dictionary in mylist:
...     values.extend([v for k, v in dictionary.items() if k == 'utterance'])
... 
>>> values
['this is nice']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [{'utterance': 10,'id': 'output454', 'utterance': 'this is nice'}]
for elem in data:
    print('{}'.format(data[elem].get('utterance')))
```

or , if only the one element in the list..

```
data = [{'utterance': 10,'id': 'output454', 'utterance': 'this is nice'}]
print('{}'.format(data[0].get('utterance')))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**: The problem here is that python `dictionary` does not allow duplicate keys so the object `'utterance': 10` is being discarded while the initialization.

**Solution**: Change your object format like

```
data = [{
    'utterance': [10,'this is nice'],
    'id': 'output454'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys in Python dictionary should be unique i.e, you cannot have duplicated keys in a python dictionary.

However, if you want a key to store multiple values, you can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

For example,

```
from collection import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d = {'utterance': [10, 'this is nice'],'id': ['output454']}
print(d.get('utterance', None))
```